# How to call multiple entries in the dictionary using the user input

Tags: python, dictionary

```
lobanDict = {0:'no', 1:'pa', 2:'re', 3:'ci', 4:'vo', 5:'mu', 6:'xa',  7:'za', 8:'bi', 9:'so'}

num = int(input("Please enter first number - "))

result = lojbanDict[num]

print(result)
```

i want to be able to type in any number and the result to be that number in lojban, e.g. 125 would be paremu

Comment: *enter first number* - means the 1st number, not a sequence

Comment: Read a string, not a number. Then iterate over characters of that string.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a for-loop to iterate over every single number in the input. Then you add the corresponding lojban to a variable, which you later print.

Comment: what if user entered `1   e 3    ww 5` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lobanDict = {0:'no', 1:'pa', 2:'re', 3:'ci', 4:'vo', 5:'mu', 6:'xa',  7:'za', 8:'bi', 9:'so'}
>>> num = '123'
>>> ''.join(lobanDict[i] for i in map(int,num))
'pareci'
```

Comment: BTW since the keys are numbers starting with 0, `lobanDict = ('no', 'pa', 're', 'ci', 'vo', 'mu', 'xa',  'za', 'bi', 'so')` should work equally well.